# Database Mail XPs' is Turned Off

Tags: sql-server

I would to ask how can I can solve this kind of prompt message in SQL Server 2012.
I already in web for possible solutions for this, I just wanna know your thoughts regarding this.

[image: Database Mail XPs' is Turned off]

Comment: Turn it ON ! https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175951(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What’s the actual question here? Define “solve” in this scenario please, especially is @Squirrel perfect comment doesn’t suffice.

Answer (score 1):

To use the procedures you have to turn on the component "Database Mail XPs"

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1
RECONFIGURE
```